# Spark SQL: Window function lag until a condition met

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am processing this dataset in spark:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|     ColumnA|     ColumnB|     Result |
+------------+------------+------------+
|      ABCDEF|    MNOPQRST|      true  |
|      123455|      UVWXYZ|      false |
|      ABCDEF|    MNOPQRST|      false | (should be true)
|      123455|      UVWXYZ|      false |
|      123455|      UVWXYZ|      false |
|      ABCDEF|    EFGHIJK |      false |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

Rules are:

1. If rank is 1 for the give partition set `Result` as true.
2. if the rank is not 1 and `ColumnA` value is `123455` set `Result` value as `false`
3. if the rank is not 1 and `ColumnA` value is not `123455` and if `ColumnB` value matches with previous row's `ColumnB` value, set Result as true. Make sure that the previous row's ColumnA's value is not `123455`

   WindowSpec w = Window.partitionBy("ColumnA, ColumnB");

   Column matchColumnB = functions.col("ColumnB").equalTo(
        functions.lag("ColumnB", 1).over(w));

Here the window function checks the previous row without considering the previous row's ColumnA value.

For example in the above dataset, Row 3's ColumnB value should be compared with Row1 not the Row2.

I tried looking at `Window.unboundedPreceding` but not sure how to use it in this scenario.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To replicate the DF:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(List(("ABCDEF","MNOPQRST"), 
                    ("123455","UVWXYZ"),
                    ("ABCDEF","MNOPQRST"),
                    ("123455","UVWXYZ"),
                    ("123455","UVWXYZ"), 
                    ("ABCDEF","EFGHIJK")))
   .toDF("ColumnA","ColumnB")
```

There are some contradictions in the supplied information, for example, your windowing implementation makes it impossible to apply mentioned conditions.

There are a few essentials to windowing analytics when it comes to working on the basis of the order of rows [rank and comparison with the previous row]

1. You need to define appropriate partition columns. If window is partitioned by `columnA` and `columnB` then their values are going to stay same for the given window. So if there is a need for comparison of `columnA` and `columnB` between `lead` or `lag` row, then the DF needs to be partitioned by some other column. **Example to show why it is *a problem***

   ```
   val w = Window.partitionBy("ColumnA", "ColumnB").orderBy("ColumnA", "ColumnB");
   df.withColumn("rank", rank.over(w)).show
   +-------+--------+----+
   |ColumnA| ColumnB|rank|
   +-------+--------+----+
   | ABCDEF| EFGHIJK|   1|
   | ABCDEF|MNOPQRST|   1|
   | ABCDEF|MNOPQRST|   1|
   | 123455|  UVWXYZ|   1|
   | 123455|  UVWXYZ|   1|
   | 123455|  UVWXYZ|   1|
   +-------+--------+----+
   ```

   Each row now acts as a window of its own. Note the order by, it is explained in point 2.
2. There is also a need of concrete `order by` statement in the windowing. Without that `rank`, 'lag', 'lead', etc. are going to non-deterministic and hence, do not make much sense. Spark tries to protect against it and windowing functions *will* throw an exception if there is no order by clause. **Example to show why it is *a problem***

   ```
   val w = Window.partitionBy("ColumnA", "ColumnB")
   df.withColumn("result", lag("columnB", 1).over(w))
   ```

   Leads to:

   ```
   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window function lag('columnB, 1, null) requires window to be ordered, please add ORDER BY clause. For example SELECT lag('columnB, 1, null)(value_expr) OVER (PARTITION BY window_partition ORDER BY window_ordering) from table;
   ```

**Solution**
To answer the question itself: I am going to consider two more columns for your question.

```
val df = sc.parallelize(List(("ABCDEF","MNOPQRST", "P1", "1"), 
                        ("123455","UVWXYZ", "P1", "2"),
                        ("ABCDEF","MNOPQRST", "P1", "3"),
                        ("123455","UVWXYZ", "P1", "4"),
                        ("123455","UVWXYZ", "P1", "5"), 
                        ("BLABLAH","UVWXYZ", "P1", "6"),
                        ("ABCDEF","EFGHIJK", "P1", "7")))
       .toDF("ColumnA","ColumnB", "ColumnP", "ColumnO")
+-------+--------+-------+-------+
|ColumnA| ColumnB|ColumnP|ColumnO|
+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| ABCDEF|MNOPQRST|     P1|      1|
| 123455|  UVWXYZ|     P1|      2|
| ABCDEF|MNOPQRST|     P1|      3|
| 123455|  UVWXYZ|     P1|      4|
| 123455|  UVWXYZ|     P1|      5|
|BLABLAH|  UVWXYZ|     P1|      5|
| ABCDEF| EFGHIJK|     P1|      6|
+-------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Here, the partitioning column is `columnP` and order by column is `ColumnO`

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("ColumnP").orderBy("ColumnO")
val dfWithWindowing = df.withColumn("lag_columnB", lag("columnB", 1).over(w))
                        .withColumn("rank", rank().over(w))
dfWithWindowing.show
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-----------+----+
|ColumnA| ColumnB|ColumnP|ColumnO|lag_columnB|rank|
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-----------+----+
| ABCDEF|MNOPQRST|     P1|      1|       null|   1|
| 123455|  UVWXYZ|     P1|      2|   MNOPQRST|   2|
| ABCDEF|MNOPQRST|     P1|      3|     UVWXYZ|   3|
| 123455|  UVWXYZ|     P1|      4|   MNOPQRST|   4|
| 123455|  UVWXYZ|     P1|      5|     UVWXYZ|   5|
|BLABLAH|  UVWXYZ|     P1|      6|     UVWXYZ|   6|
| ABCDEF| EFGHIJK|     P1|      7|     UVWXYZ|   7|
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-----------+----+
```

Now we have all the information necessary to carry out required computation. There is no specification in the rule about value of result when it is not meeting any of the condition, the implementation considers this as true.

```
val resultDF = dfWithWindowing.withColumn("result", when($"rank"==="1",true).otherwise(
                              when($"ColumnA"==="123455", false).otherwise(
                                    when($"ColumnB"===$"lag_columnB", true).otherwise(true)
                                 )
                              )
                          ).drop("ColumnP", "ColumnO","lag_columnB","rank")
+-------+--------+------+
|ColumnA| ColumnB|result|
+-------+--------+------+
| ABCDEF|MNOPQRST|  true|
| 123455|  UVWXYZ| false|
| ABCDEF|MNOPQRST|  true|
| 123455|  UVWXYZ| false|
| 123455|  UVWXYZ| false|
|BLABLAH|  UVWXYZ|  true|
| ABCDEF| EFGHIJK|  true|
+-------+--------+------+
```

To know more about windowing, please refer to https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html